# Fullcalendar Google Calendar event source of iCloud calendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, icloud

I have an iCloud calendar that I subscribed my google calendar to for events from a family member to be part of my fullcalendar view. When the events display from this calendar only they are in UTC or GMT, and not EST like every other event. I tried to use the timezone setting with no change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  timezoneParam: 'America/Detroit',
  scrollTime: '08:00:00',
  height: 523,
  nowIndicator: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
  },
  googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyBGoAWoq_RU5lyNMEFKnF9_aYMQfRXNpOo',

    eventSources: [
      {
        googleCalendarId: '1qfkommnmcjbi7u47ogu7m26m5n4gp09@import.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'icloud',
        timezoneParam: 'America/Detroit'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'holiday'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'in8pu75b4ajd8j5ph94r803uu0@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'cavs'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'oeacpqtr12n0373dlsujm4blks@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'indians'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: '78nnbfdatki5q5gh7u954c4828@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'mount'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: '1l7b07itoevm0su5tia2k9v07k@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'osu'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: '2vbu9olhcabjs4r8fdr91vlcq4@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'nd'
      }
    ],

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.qtip({
        content: event.description
      });
    }

});
});
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am hoping there is something in my code and not an issue with subscribing to the calendar.

Comment: what is the default timezone of the actual google calendar? Is it different to the others? And exactly which of the ones listed above is actually giving you the problem, just to clarify?

Comment: The first one className iCloud. It is a subscribed iCloud calendar. Google changes the time zone to UTC.

Comment: So if google is forcing it to be UTC at that end, then probably the data coming from google is already in UTC, so not fullCalendar's fault? It can only deal with the data it's given. You can easily check what comes back from the google calendar by checking for the relevant ajax request in your browser tools and viewing the response. Read how the timezone setting in fullCalendar works: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone The server is expected to co-operate with this. Not sure that google will be doing that. You could also check the source of gcal.js in case it intereferes in any way

Comment: Meanwhile have you gone all the way back to iCloud and checked the timezone there, at the root? I don't know if Google can read or take account of that when it subscribes to the calendar, but worth checking anyhow.

Comment: I did there as well. It’s funny cause on the google calendar webpage they show up correct time zone just not in full calendars render.

Comment: so maybe the iCloud feed supplies a timezone offset or something. You could maybe check, if you have the URL. Then compare with what google supplies to fullCalendar.